# Python 3 detailed control of I/O of another process

Tags: python, io, subprocess, pipe, python-3.3

In python 3 (on Linux or MacOSX10.8) how can I get a parent process to read just a prompt (that does not include `\n`) issued by a subprocess, not the entire buffer till `\n`?

```
# program names.py
print("I am Joe.")                   #1print
name = input("What is your name? ")  #2prompt
print("Hi", name, "!")               #3print

# program parent.py (in python 3.3.0)
import subprocess
import sys
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "names.py"],
                      bufsize=0,
                      stdin =subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                      shell=False,
                      universal_newlines=True
                    )
print(p.stdout.readline(), end='')
p.stdin.write("Sue\n")
# The next print will produce the output of 2prompt + 3print:
print(p.stdout.readline(), end='')
```

When I run `parent.py` it prints:

```
I am Joe.
What is your name? Hi Sue !
```

How to modify `parent.py` so that it prints:

```
I am Joe.
What is your name? 
Hi Sue !
```

That is, how to extract separately the output produced by prompt and print?

Comment: Might not be exactly what you need, but you could print a newline at the start of the "Hi"...

Answer (score 2):

`readline()` reads from `names.py` until the next `\n`, where what you need is a "read as much as there is right now". Time is an additional factor here, since you basically have to detect, when `names.py` is waiting (expecting input).

Basically, you need a `read()`-operation with a timeout. You could start a separate thread that reads from `names.py` byte by byte into a buffer. You can then `join(timeout)` this thread and access its buffer.

Comment: note: if the child process buffers the prompt then reading byte-by-byte won't help (your process just won't see any output from the child until it flushes its buffers). See [Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect#Q%3a_Why_not_just_use_a_pipe_.28popen.28.29.29.3F)

Comment: Yes. I'm assuming that `input()` flushes the buffer, as should any program before prompting for input.

Comment: you're right [`input()` flushes sys.stdout even if it is redirected to a pipe](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9fc4a1ebe652/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1822) though [the docs doesn't mention it](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how the prompt looks like then you could use string manipulation to get desired output as [@Michael suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243401/python-3-detailed-control-of-i-o-of-another-process#comment22623381_14243401):

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen([sys.executable, "names.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
          universal_newlines=True)
output = p.communicate("Sue\n")[0]
prompt = "name? "
print(output.replace(prompt, prompt + "\n"))
```

#### Output

```
I am Joe.
What is your name? 
Hi Sue !
```

If you don't know how the prompt looks like then [the timeout-based solution suggested by @Exp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15891303/4279) might not work if the child process uses block-buffering when it is run non-interactively. Though it does work for the `names.py`. Here's a timeout-based solution that uses `select` instead of threads to read the output:

```
import os
import sys
from select import select
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

timeout = 1 # seconds
with Popen([sys.executable, 'names.py'],
           stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,  bufsize=0) as p:
    while True:
        ready = select([p.stdout], [], [], timeout)[0]
        if ready: # there is something to read
            data = os.read(p.stdout.fileno(), 512)
            if not data: # EOF
                break
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(data) # echo subprocess output
        elif p.poll() is None: # timeout, but subprocess is still running
            print("") # print newline after the prompt
            p.stdin.write(b"Sue\n") # answer the prompt
        else: # subprocess exited
            break
```

It produces the same output as the first code example after a delay.

In general, `pexpect` could be used to emulate interactive mode for a subprocess.

If you know how the prompt looks like:

```
import sys
import pexpect

print(pexpect.run(sys.executable + " -mnames", events={r'name\? ': 'Sue\n'}))
# note: it echos our answer too (it can be avoided if necessary)
```

#### Output

```
I am Joe.
What is your name? Sue
Hi Sue !
```

Here's a timeout-based solution that avoids echoing the answer back:

```
import sys
import pexpect # pip install pexpect-u

child = pexpect.spawn(sys.executable + " -mnames", timeout=1)
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout # echo subprocess output
child.expect(pexpect.TIMEOUT)
print("") # print newline after the prompt
child.setecho(False) # don't echo our answer
child.sendline('Sue')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
child.close()
```

To reproduce it using `subprocess`, `pty` module could be used:

```
import os
import pty
import sys
from select import select
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT

timeout = 1 # seconds
master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()
with Popen([sys.executable, 'names.py'],
           stdin=slave_fd, stdout=slave_fd, stderr=STDOUT,
           bufsize=0) as p:
    while True:
        ready = select([master_fd], [], [], timeout)[0]
        if ready: # there is something to read
            data = os.read(master_fd, 512)
            if not data: # EOF
                break
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(data) # echo subprocess output
        elif p.poll() is None: # timeout, but subprocess is still running
            # assume that child process waits for input after printing the prompt
            answer = b"Sue\n"
            os.write(master_fd, answer) # asnwer the prompt
            os.read(master_fd, len(answer)) # don't echo our answer
        else: # subprocess exited
            break
    os.close(slave_fd)
    os.close(master_fd)
```